# PHP function outputting data out of order

Tags: php, function

I wrote a function that queries the a database to find out what a specific users role(s) once logged in using their user ID from the session. However when I went to test it. It output the correct data but it was not in the right place. For example when I log in with one of my users whos username is "Fred12" it says "Hello there fred12 your roles are the above it it has the users role in one long string. See attached screenshot [image: Screenshot of issue]. The roles should be on the same line as everything else. Below I included the code for both my function and the page which the text in question appears. I have posted other questions using this same code as I had some other issues before getting to this point.

**Function**

```
function getRoleName($conn, $id)
{
        $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
        $sql = "SELECT 
                * FROM users
                INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.usersId = user_roles.user_id
                INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.role_id 
                WHERE users.usersId = ?;";
        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
        //$stmt -> mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
        $stmt -> bind_param("s", $_SESSION['userid']);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $result = $stmt->get_result();
        if($result->num_rows > 0){

            while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                if ($row['role_name'] == 0) {
                $array = array($row['role_name']);
                foreach ($array as $value) {
                        echo ($value);
                }
                }else{
                echo "no role!";
                }//end else
            }//end while
        }else{
        echo "JPS Says go away from me!";
        }//end if numrows
```

**Index**

```
<?php 
include_once 'header.php';
include_once 'includes/dbh.inc.php';

?>
<?php  
if (isset($_SESSION["useruid"])) 
{
    echo "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"]. "&nbsp;your roles are &nbsp;" . getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"])."</p>";

}//end isset
    
                ?>
<?php 
include_once 'footer.php';
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do

```
 echo "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"]. "&nbsp;your roles are &nbsp;" . getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"])."</p>";
```

it *first* has to generate the string to echo, so *before* it echoes it will basically do

```
$tmp = "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"]. "&nbsp;your roles are &nbsp;" . getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"])."</p>";
echo $tmp;
```

because you are calling `getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"])`, which *itself* echoes, that will be echoed first.

You need to just *return* the role names:

```
function getRoleName($conn, $id)
{
    $roles = [];
    $id = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $sql = "SELECT 
            * FROM users
            INNER JOIN user_roles ON users.usersId = user_roles.user_id
            INNER JOIN roles ON user_roles.role_id = roles.role_id 
            WHERE users.usersId = ?;";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    //$stmt -> mysqli_stmt_prepare($stmt, $sql);
    $stmt -> bind_param("s", $_SESSION['userid']);
    $stmt -> execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
            if ($row['role_name'] == 0) {
            $array = array($row['role_name']);
            foreach ($array as $value) {
                $roles[] = $value
            }
            }else{
                $roles[] = "no role!";
            }//end else
        }//end while
    }else{
        throw new Exception('JSP says go away!');
    }//end if numrows
    return $roles;
}

echo "<p>Hello there " . $_SESSION["useruid"]. "&nbsp;your roles are &nbsp;" . implode(",", getRoleName($conn, $_SESSION["userid"]))."</p>";
```